# Change original creator of EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks

Is it possible to change the original creator of an EKS cluster to another role. I still have access to the cluster, with both the original creator role and the new one I want to transfer the cluster to.

The new role is now encoded in de aws_auth config map, but we locked ourselves out by deleting the config map (in a terraform update). We were able to restore it using the creator role, but we'd rather not use that one anymore.

Is it possible to update the creator user, or do I need to create a new cluster with the proper role, and then transfer everything over?

From the Amazon Docs:

```
You don't need to add cluster_creator to the aws-auth ConfigMap to get admin access to the Amazon EKS cluster. By default, the cluster_creator has admin access to the Amazon EKS cluster that it created.
```

Comment: From what I know, you cannot change the creator because it is a default user/role stored by eks and not stored in aws-auth configmap. The purpose of aws-auth is to provide authorization to users/roles/groups.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to change the creator of EKS cluster. If you want to allow more entities (IAM User or IAM Role) to access your cluster, you can add it to `aws-auth` configmap.

Auto granting admin access to the creator (IAM User or IAM Role) of EKS cluster is a "fireman switch" to prevent you from lock yourself outside. The rule resides on the control plane and you can't modify it.

Comment: "to creator", can you elaborate on this? Is the creator an IAM User or an IAM Role, or something different?

Comment: @JimAho The creater (IAM user or IAM role) of EKS cluster.

Comment: Alright now I understand, and this is an important part for everyone else reading this: the creator of the cluster is not necessarily a person in the sense of your colleague that created the cluster. An owner or "creator" of the EKS cluster can be an IAM User **or** an IAM Role as a **role** is in itself an entity. In our case it turned out that we had an old IAM Role that was supposed to be deleted by our infra team but we asked them to keep it. This was the only way for us to make sure we actually kept the owner of the cluster, and allowed us to switch to the owner IAM Role whenever needed.